# my invisible dropdownlist does not become visible again at visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, drop-down-menu, visibility

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and I created a site (.aspx).

I have 2 radiobuttons, and a DropDownList.
I want to have an invisible dropdownlist and whenever I click on the one radiobutton then the downdownlist to appear! 
I have added a code like this but nothing changes and I can't understand why!!

```
protected void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
        DropDownList4.Visible = true;
    else
        DropDownList4.Visible = false;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList4.Visible=false;
}
```

The only thing I am getting, is an invisible dropdownlist than never becomes visible!
Both of my radiobuttons have the same action "radiobutton_checkedchanged" ..

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code is ok , set AutoPostBack property of radiobutton to true

since `RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` events occurs after page load

it will work no need for checking !IsPostBack

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       DropDownList4.Visible=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still, nothing happens... my dropdownlist is invisible!

Comment: Just verify that your RadioButton_CheckedChanged is associated with RadioButton1 button